# Stop sysstat sar

Tags: linux, sar

How to stop sar collecting system activity without uninstalling sysstat? I have used `systemctl stop sysstat` but as I understand from running `sar` it continues collecting system activity.

Answer (score 0):

Sar is ofttimes installed as a cron job. I would look for `/usr/lib/sa/sa1` in `/etc/cron*` and `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/*` and comment it out or something to disable it.